# Error with Youtube after installing VLC

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, video-player

I have installed VLC media player from Software Centre. After that, my laptop can't play videos in Youtube (I use FireFox), too many lags. How can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advanced.

**Ps:**   I have uninstalled VLC and everything is fine again. But I want to use VLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open the Firefox Add-ons Manager and disable the VLC plugin.